wierd split sewing edges
so what i think i need to do to get this accomplished is flattening these edges.
but the ways every one says to do it is s + "what ever axis and it worked for a few of the sides but for the other ones i need something else so any ideas?
here is the blend file.


The reason is the order of modifiers on the stack. Try this order: mirror, cloth, weld, solidify, subdivision. Then run the cloth simulation. For better performance you can turn off the last 3 modifier while the simulation runs.

@Blunder You should add that as an answer. I'm not familiar enough with clothing to know which order the modifiers should be added. I just concentrated on modelling errors! Having just tried it, the seams are indeed fixed but the cloth still needs centring relative to the model otherwise it looks like an attempt at an 'off-the-shoulder design! :^)

it worked thanks now i've got to apologise to my poor fps lol

You have three problems, two being with your underlying model rather than the shirt!
Select the model and in Edit mode, change to Local view with the /(forward-slash) key. Then turn off the Mirror and Subdiv modifiers by clicking the arrowed monitor icons and go into Face mode. You'll see that you have internal faces on your model which I've selected. Hit X > Faces to delete them.

Now turn the modifiers back on, select All and hit M > MergebyDistance.

You'll briefly see a message saying "Removed 8 vertice(s)" on the bottom status bar and the seam where the shoulder meets the rest of the body will have disappeared.
If you now come back out of Local view with the / key and run the animation the shirt should fit pretty well.
There's still a slight problem on one shoulder, but I think that's because the shirt isn't aligned on the centre line with the model. - It's slightly off-centre to the right in front view and it looks as if the front and rear faces aren't in line hence the seams down the side, but I'll have to leave that one for you to sort out. - I'm going to bed!

UPDATE:
I've now added the reordered modifiers suggested by Blunder in his comment above and that does indeed fix the problem and it's not necessary to centre the cloth object, but you should still sort out the internal faces and merge the vertices on the Cube object for best results.
You can hold the mouse down on the area of the modifier arrowed below and drag it up or down to reorder it in the list.


@GordonBrinkmann Both keys work here under Windows! (Bottom-right on the keyboard next to the right-shift key.) Never heard of the Shift + 7 one! - That's ampersand on a UK keyboard.

Oh damn, I was mixing up my German QWERTZ keyboard layout with the US/international QWERTY layout :D

You have to think internationally on this forum! :^)

I usually do, guess why I said Numpad / - you know, on my keyboard there is no / on the numpad, there is a ÷  instead ;)

Lots of folks use a laptop without a numpad which is why I just said the forward-slash key in my answer...

Yes, I got that now no need to explain yourself :D  The laptop reason was why I thought about making sure not to use the one I have here on my keyboard with Shift+7, because without the numpad, this will not work here and since I do not use a laptop, I do not know if for QWERTZ users with numpad emulation there is a key which they can use. (So maybe still interesting for people who use a QWERTZ keyboard, I know for a fact there are quite a few here.)

thank you guys so much ive spent months on this model.

Thanks. Please mark my answer above as correct. (Green arrow when marked).
